# Lemma of Bézout

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a PID. By the Lemma of Bézout I mean the statement that for elements $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in A$ we have $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=((a_1,\ldots,a_n))$ where $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ denotes *a* greatest common divisor of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. Is the following proof correct? Proof: as $A$ is a PID we must have $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(a)$ for some $a\in A$ (hence $a|a_i$). A guy $c\in A$ is a common divisor of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ iff $(c)\supset (a)$ iff $c|a$, so that $a$ must be a gcd.

Are there generalizations of the Lemma of Bézout to, say, factorial rings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bezout's Lemma holds in, well, [Bezout rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain). A non-example is $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, here we have $(2,x) \neq (1)=(\mathrm{ggT}(2,x))$.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. btw where are you from? oh wait, looking at your notation it is evident